# Swift: Save an Array of Objects with another Array of Objects inside into NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, object, nsuserdefaults

I've been working though my first app, but I'm at a point where I need to save the users data, but can't. I have an array of objects, with a "Questions" object array inside as well:

```
struct Question {
    let question: String
    let answer: String
}

struct UserEntry {
    let date: String
    let questions: [Question]
}

let userEntry = [UserEntries(date: todayDate, questions: [Question(answer: mood), Question(question: q1Text, answer: q1Answer), Question(question: q2Text, answer: q2Answer)])]
```

But, this is throwing the error: Cannot convert value of type 'ThisViewController.Question' to expected element type 'UserEntries.Question'. Following another stack answer have also created a class for it:

```
class UserEntries: NSObject, NSCoding {
struct Question {
    var question: String
    var answer: String
}

var date: String
var questions: [Question]

init(date: String, questions: [Question]) {
    self.date = date
    self.questions = questions
}

required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let date = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "date") as! String
    let question = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "questions")
    self.init(date: date, questions: question as! [UserEntries.Question])
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(date, forKey: "date")
    aCoder.encode(questions, forKey: "questions")
}
}
```

I am saving the data like so:

```
let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: userEntry)
UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "allEntries")
```

I am very confused with what is wrong, any help or guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have created the `Question` object in two places.

Take a look at the error message:

> Cannot convert value of type 'ThisViewController.Question' to expected element type 'UserEntries.Question'.

Now look at the code you provided, first what I guess is from `YourViewController`:

```
struct Question {
    let question: String
    let answer: String
}

struct UserEntry {
    let date: String
    let questions: [Question]
}

let userEntry = [UserEntries(date: todayDate, questions: [Question(answer: mood), Question(question: q1Text, answer: q1Answer), Question(question: q2Text, answer: q2Answer)])]
```

And then:

```
class UserEntries: NSObject, NSCoding {
struct Question {
    var question: String
    var answer: String
}
...
```

So...You have the `Question` defined in your `ThisViewController` and then you have another `Question` defined inside your `UserEntries` class.

The compiler tells you that it thought you were using the `ThisViewController.Question`, which you can not add to a `UserEntries.Question` as those are two different things to the compiler.

### Solution

As you've moved your `Question` and `UserEntry` logic into the `UserEntries` class, which conforms to `NSCoding`, you no longer need it in `YourViewController` as well.

So, delete the `Question` and `UserEntry` structs from your `YourViewController` so you only have a `Question` in `UserEntries` and things should (hopefully) work again.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! But... it now throws - Use of unresolved identifier 'Question', but haven't I already declared that in the class?

Comment: @Anthony Yeah but inside your `UserEntries` right? So instead of it being a `Question` it is now a `UserEntries.Question` since it is an inner class. If you think that is too confusing you can keep your original `Question` and have that conform to `NSCoding` and then delete the `UserEntries.Question` instead. The important thing is that you use the _same_ `Question` type in both places. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yep! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, glad you got it solved. On to the next one problem right :)

Comment: Speaking of problems, back to the original question, it fails to save the array with "unrecognized selector sent to instance". I feel like there is something wrong with the class.

Comment: @Anthony sorry...what was the original question? Wasn't that related to you using two versions of a `Question`, or am I misunderstanding?